# TestDome - Malware Analysis in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, iteration

I'm practicing this [problem](https://www.testdome.com/questions/cpp/malware-analysis/105866) on TestDome, and I found myself stuck with the final step of the malware process, namely, replacing the correct position with a value of 0. My program accurately prints out the values until we come across the last positions, where instead of printing out the next to last values as such `3, 3, 0`, we get `0, 0, 0`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Update: The problematic is that we need to find a way to not eliminate the first two 77 values.

std::vector<int> simulate(const std::vector<int>& entries) {
    std::vector<int> tempEntries{};
    std::vector<int> simEntries{ entries };

    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator itX = entries.begin();
        itX != entries.end(); itX++) {
        std::vector<int>::const_iterator itRightT{}; // Iterator of right T position. 
        itRightT = itX + 4;
        if (itRightT != entries.end()) {
            if (*itX <= *itRightT) {
                tempEntries.push_back(*itX);
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator itReverseX = entries.rbegin();
        itReverseX != entries.rend(); itReverseX++) {
        std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator itLeftT{}; // Iterator of left T position.
        itLeftT = itReverseX + 3;
        if (itLeftT != entries.rend()) {
            if (*itReverseX <= *itLeftT) {
                tempEntries.push_back(*itReverseX);
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::sort(tempEntries.begin(), tempEntries.end());

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = simEntries.begin();
        it != simEntries.end(); it++) {
        if (std::find(tempEntries.begin(), tempEntries.end(), *it) != tempEntries.end()) {
            *it = 0;
        }
    }

    // Desired Result: 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0
    //  Actual Result: 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    return simEntries; 
}

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> result = simulate({ 1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3 });
    for (int value : result)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
    // Expected output
    // 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0
}
#endif
```

I tried to search for STL functions capable of accomplishing the task above. However, I wasn't able to find any one that was particularly amazing. For instance, `std::set_intersection` accomplishes the comparison very well; however, I can't modify the elements directly. (Perhaps there is a way to work around this limitation, but I do not know it.)

Any help in solving this problem is appreciated.

Comment: `itRightT = itX + 4;` exhibits undefined behavior when `itX` is close enough to the end of the vector. It is illegal to increment an iterator past `end()`.

Comment: `tempEntries` stores values, rather than indexes into the original sequence. If a value ends up in `tempEntries`, the program ultimately replaces **all** occurrences of that value with zero. But that's incorrect - in the original problem statement, it's entirely possible that some occurrences should be replaced but not others. This is what you observe - in your example, only one occurrence of `3` should be replaced, but instead all of them get replaced.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In regard to your first comment, we break out of the `for` loop before incrementing past `end()`; therefore, we avoid any potential runtime errors. Admittedly, there might be a better and safer way to accomplish the same result. Lastly, in your second comment, you mentioned storing the indexes instead of the values. Could you show me an example of how to do that, or provide a link?

Comment: `tempEntries` should be a vector of indexes, or a vector of iterators if you'd rather. It should store positions into the original sequence that need to be replaced, not values. Implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to @bijan goshayeshi for the helpful suggestion! Thanks to their input, this revised C++ program successfully passed all 4 test cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> simulate(const std::vector<int>& entries) {
    if (entries.size() < 4)
        return entries;

    std::vector<int> simEntries{ entries };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> tempEntries{};

    for (auto itX = std::begin(simEntries); itX != std::end(simEntries) - 4; ++itX) {
       const auto rightT = itX + 4;
       if (*itX <= *rightT)
           tempEntries.push_back(itX);
    }

    for (auto itX = std::begin(simEntries) + 3; itX != std::end(simEntries); ++itX) {
        const auto leftT = itX - 3;
        if (*itX <= *leftT)
            tempEntries.push_back(itX);
    }

    for (auto it = std::begin(simEntries); it != std::end(simEntries); ++it) {
        if (std::find(std::begin(tempEntries), std::end(tempEntries), it) != std::end(tempEntries)) {
            *it = 0;
    }

    return simEntries;
}

#ifndef RunTests
int main() {
    std::vector<int> result = simulate({ 1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3 });
    for (int value : result) {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
    // Expected output
    // 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is almost correct, but there is small mistake in

```
if (leftT <= (simEntries.begin() + 3)) {
        continue;
```

since the loop counter starts from 0, then the condition must be

```
if (leftT <= (simEntries.begin() + 2)) {
        continue;
```

so just change 3 to 2 and the you can pass all the tests.

You can also write them in only one loop, see the following python solution:

```
def simulate(entries):

result = entries[:]

window_size = 8
first_half_length = 3
second_half_length = 4

for i in range(len(entries)):
    X = entries[i]
    T1 = None
    T2 = None
    if i >= first_half_length:
        T1 = entries[i-first_half_length]

    if (i + second_half_length < len(entries)): T2 = entries[i + second_half_length]

    if T1 is not None and X <= T1:
        result[i] = 0
    if T2 is not None and X <= T2:
        result[i] = 0
return result

records = [1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3]
print(simulate(records))

# Expected output
# [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
stack = []
size = len(entries)
for i in range(size):
    x = i - 3
    y = i + 4
    cur = entries[i]
    if (x >= 0 and cur <= entries[x]) or (y < size and cur <= entries[y]):
        stack.append(0)
    else:
        stack.append(cur)
return stack
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: The question is also specific to C++ ... This code is not C++